# Skip directory creation if directory already exists

Tags: java, nio

I want to create a Quartz job that reads .csv files and moves them when the file is processed. I tried this:

```
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {

    File directoryPath = new File("C:\\csv\\nov");
    // Create a new subfolder called "processed" into source directory
    try {
        Files.createDirectory(Path.of(directoryPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/processed"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    .......................
}
```

When I run the code a second time I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\csv\nov\processed
```

Is there some way to make a check for this directory and skip directory creation? I can remove the line `throw new RuntimeException(e);` but I'm looking for a better way to handle the case.

Comment: Can you please specify which libraries and java version you are using ?

Comment: if  ( !file.exists() || !file.isDirectory() ) Files.createDirectory(....

Comment: I use Java 17, OpenCSV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
try {
    Path path = Path.of(directoryPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/processed");

    // Check first if the file not exist
    if (!Files.exists(path)) {
        Files.createDirectory(path);
    }
} catch(..)
```

Comment: I'd prefer `directoryPath.toPath().resolve("processed")` as more concise & idiomatic

Comment: @GyroGearless Yes good one `Path path = Path.of(directoryPath.toPath().resolve("processed").toUri());` with `.toUri()` in the end

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Files.createDirectories(path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) which will not report an error if the directory exists on the second and subsequent runs.

Note that the behaviour is slightly different, as `Files.createDirectories(path)` creates all directory levels that don't exist.

The call will give `FileAlreadyExistsException` if the path exists and isn't a directory, but does not report any error second time if the path exists and is a directory.